# Pass data from custom field on user to React in Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using React with Meteor. I need to know what groups a member is a part of and show those groups on the users profile page.

All users join the 'newbie' group when they first join. The ID for this group is 1:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.groups = [1];
  return user;
});
```

In my server/main.js Im publishing this:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: { groups: 1 } });
});
```

With the Meteor dev tools I can now see the user's groups. How should I pass this data to React? I suppose there are different ways to do this but my first thought was to use setState in App.js.

It seems Meteor.user() isn't available in componentDidMount when I try the following in my App.js:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(Meteor.user());
  }
```

Comment: use `createContainer` to load the page only when `Meteor.user()` is loaded

Comment: Im passing a flag with ready: userSub.ready() in my App's withTracker, is that what you mean?

Comment: So should I use setState in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: @Evans absolutely not. Calling `setState` in `componentDidUpdate`, `render` etc. will cause endless re-render. Think about it.

Comment: @Evans `createContainer` is now deprecated and replaced with [`withTracker`](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker)

Comment: Better to treat the user data as props rather than state. But you're on the right track - since `Meteor.user()` isn't available right away you have to use `withTracker` to make the container reactive.